# how to get MAC Address from paired Bluetooth devices using google chrome API

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, bluetooth

I am trying using Google chrome API,
example here -> ["Web Bluetooth / Device Info Sample"](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html).
but unfortunately the "BluetoothDevice" object contain only {id, name, gatt}.

I need to get the MAC Address value as the following:[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can be found with *chrome.sessions.getDevices()* but it only includes all your other devices, not the current one.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, but the "sessions" is undefined, using windows 10, chrome